# Why folder does not get bound?

Tags: docker, go

I am trying to create a container for testing purpose with https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient?tab=doc as follows:

```
client, err := docker.NewClientFromEnv()
NoError(t, err, err)

ctx := context.Background()

gogs, err := client.CreateContainer(docker.CreateContainerOptions{
    Name: "gogs",
    Config: &docker.Config{
        Image: "gogs/gogs:0.11.91",
    },
    HostConfig: &docker.HostConfig{
        PublishAllPorts: true,
        AutoRemove:      true,
        Binds:           []string{dest, "/data"},
        PortBindings: map[docker.Port][]docker.PortBinding{
            "3000/tcp": {{HostIP: "0.0.0.0", HostPort: "8888"}}},
    },
    Context: ctx,
})
NoError(t, err, err)

err = client.StartContainer(gogs.ID, nil)
NoError(t, err, err)
```

The problem is, the bind does not work. What am I trying to achieve is:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8888:3000 --name=gogs --mount type=bind,source=`pwd`/gogs/data,target=/data gogs/gogs
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When mounting a path you can attach `Mounts` to the `HostConfig` like this:

```
&container.HostConfig{
    Mounts: []mount.Mount{
        {
            Type:   mount.TypeBind,
            Source: "/source",
            Target: "/target",
        },
    },
}
```

This will mount `/source` in to the container.

Comment: Mounts does not exist in https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient?tab=doc#HostConfig.

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient?tab=doc#HostConfig

But, I can see the `Mounts`. Here it is: 9th from the bottom.